# Getting HTTP Error 500 on following code

Tags: php, mysql

I'm pretty new to PHP. Why am I getting internal error on the following bit code:

```
// DB connection (working)

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $arr = array(); // array for errors later used with http_build_query
```

Parsing username:

```
    $username = test_input($_POST["myusername"]);
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $username)) {
      $arr["userErr"] = "1"; // Invalid username!
    } else {
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username = '$username';";
      $result = $conn->query($sql);
      if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $arr["userErr"] = "2"; // Username already registered!
      } else {
        $arr["userErr"] = "0"; // no problems
        $ok++;
      }
    }
```

Parsing password:

```
    $password = test_input($_POST["mypassword"]);
    if (strlen($password) < 6) {
      $arr["passErr"] = "1"; // Password is too short!
    } else if (strlen($password) > 30) {
      $arr["passErr"] = "2"; // Password it too long!
    } else {
      $arr["passErr"] = "0"; // no problems
      $ok++;
    }
```

Parsing email:

```
    $email = test_input($_POST["myemail"]);
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $arr["emailErr"] = "1"; // Invalid email format
    } else {
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE email = '$email';";
      $result = $conn->query($sql);
      if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $arr["emailErr"] = "2"; // Email already registered!
      } else {
        $arr["emailErr"] = "0";
        $ok++;
      }
    }
```

If it's all good we send the data to the database (if $ok == 3) and send the user back to index with a successful message (located in index.php):

```
    if($ok == 3) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name (username, password, email)
VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email');";
$conn->query($sql);
header("location:index.php?" . "good=true");}
```

Otherwise, we send the user to index with an error message containing the information for the warnings:

```
} else {
  header("location:index.php?" . http_build_query($arr));
}
}
```

Comment: Add a `?` in `"location:index.php" . http_build_query($arr))`: `location:index.php?`

Comment: Your `SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE email = $email` and `SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username = $username;` are invalid and open to SQL injections. Strings need to be quotes in SQL. The `test_input` is useless in preventing SQL injections.

Comment: anytime you get a 5xx error, your first stop should be the webserver's error log.

Comment: I edited the mistakes but I'm still getting the 500 error, and I have no idea what's up in this [log](http://pastebin.com/VmfYXkGX)

Comment: That is your access log, not your error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved!** Thanks to @u_mulder and @chris85 for pointing out the mistakes, also finally realised I was using the wrong connection method which was part of the problem.

$conn is supposed to be mysql_query